# Mapping takes an insane amount of gas

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, gas, mapping, decentralization

I am building out an Ethereum smart contract that allows users to create listings.  Here is part of my contract, the part thatis the culprit of the gas usage:

```
 struct LiveListing {
     uint id;
     string name;
     string description;
     string condition;
     uint price;
     address buyer;
     address seller;       
 }

 mapping(uint => LiveListing) public liveListingsMapping;
 uint id;

     function createListing(string _name, string _description, string _condition, uint _price) public  { 
         id++;
         LiveListing memory listing = LiveListing({name: _name, 
         description: _description, 
         condition: _condition, 
         price: _price, 
         seller: msg.sender, 
         id: id,
         buyer: 0x0,
         });
         liveListingsMapping[id] = listing;
    }
```

When the mapping and my assignment of a listing to an id is commented out, the gas goes from over 1,000,000 to 300,000.  Also, the create listing goes from 300,000 to around 21,000-22,000.  Any advice?  Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not the Mapping that takes a lot of gas; it's the fact that you are storing a lot of data in a large object.

A concept that you should be clear about is that when you store data in Ethereum, it *currently* has to be stored by every node in the network (excluding light nodes). Therefore, there is a gas cost associated with storing data that increases as the amount of data you want to store increases. The idea is to decentivize storing lots of data on-chain.

**Potential solutions**
Here are some potential solutions to consider:

1. **Think about the datatypes you are using**

For example uint is an alias for uint256 - which would allow you to have around 1.1579209e+77 listings.

Do you expect there to be more than 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 listings? If not then perhaps uint64 would be more suitable.

Similarly, is `condition` more like an enum; could you store 1-2 characters in `bytes2` instead of requiring all of the memory used to store a `string`?

2. **Store some of the data off chain**

Do other contracts need to read all of the data? If not, then perhaps the data doesn't have to be stored in Ethereum and can be stored off-chain in IPFS or something similar.

Maybe you could take some inspiration from [ERC-721](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues/721) - that defines a `tokenMetadata` function and storage standard, for storing token metadata off-chain - and some of the implementing tokens (e.g. [CrytoKitties](https://github.com/axiomzen/cryptokitties-bounty/tree/master/contracts)).